# how to output python celery standard log to both console and logfile

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I have a question about how to send celery log in **default format** output to both console (stdout) and logfile.

```
log default format: "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(message)s"
task log default format: "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] 
                          [%(task_name)s(%(task_id)s)] %(message)s"
```

I start up the celery app using:

```
celery_app = Celery()
celery_app.start(argv=["celery", "worker", "-l", "info"]
```

this only sends the full celery log to console (stdout).

When I do:

```
celery_app = Celery()
celery_app.start(argv=["celery", "worker", "-l", "info", "--logfile='./tasks.log'"]
```

this only sends the full celery log to logfile (tasks.log).

**how can I send the full celery log to both console and logfile at the same time?**

I tried using logging.config.dictConfig(config) to set up both streamHandler and fileHandler to output to console and logfile. This way doesn't allow me to include the task_id and task_name in the default celery log format because the task_id and task_name require to use TaskFormatter class.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is to hook into either `celery.signals.setup_logging` or `celery.signals.after_setup_task_logger`.  You can add an additional logging handler in your signal callback function.  As an aside, even if you use `dictConfig`, you can still add the `TaskFormatter` to your logging config.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have an example of how to include TaskFormatter to the dictConfig setup?